# While loop in third funtion of my pokemon game is going into infinite loop

Tags: python, while-loop

The while loops jacked up

Heres what i tried, i wanted it to take the users input and give them answer. and if the input was spelled wrong (the input is not any of the if statement options) then i want it to say u spelled it wrong and then go back and then loop again. That worked fine but when the if statement is == to the input the function just tells them they spelled it wrong when it should run the if statements.

Main point is i really need help

```
def who_do_you_want_to_be(x):
    print("you will be "+x)
    print("Great choice!")
    
def who_do_you_want_to_face(a, x):
    print(a + " will face "+x + "\n" )
    
def Where_do_u_want_to_fight(a):
    
    while True:
  
        if a=="pokemon stadium":
            print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
            print("Well also give you pokemon stadium music too but im in a rush")
            break
            
        elif a=="planet namek":
            print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
            print("Well also give you planet namek music too but im in a rush")
            break
            
        elif a=="the leaf village":
            print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
            print("Well also give you the leaf village music too but im in a rush")
            break
            
        else:
            print("Spell it correctly!\n")
            place=input("choose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower()
    
character=input("write what pokemon you want to be (charzard, pikachu, or Gyarados) :").lower() 
who_do_you_want_to_be(character)

choice=input("\nwrite what pokemon you want to face (charzard, pikachu, or Gyarados) :").lower()    
who_do_you_want_to_face(character, choice)

place=input("\nchoose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower()
Where_do_u_want_to_fight(place)
```

Comment: In the `Where_do_u_want_to_fight()` function, if `a` does not match any of the choices, you're assigning the new user input to a variable named `place`.  Which means `a` never changes, and the loop runs forever.

Comment: `place=input [...]` in your function doesn't change `a`, which is what your `if`s check

Comment: Rather than passing the response to your function, instead have the function prompt for the input, at the top of the `while` loop.  As it is now, the input never changes in the function, so if it's bad, of course you go into an infinite loop - you forgot to ask for new inout.

Comment: i took out the new user input which is the last line on the third function, now everything works good but if you type in a choice place thats not in the if statements instead of saying the spellings wrong try again it say the spellings wrong all day long. basically another infinite loop. what can i do

Comment: Did you mean to have `a=input("choose ...` as the last line of the third function?

Comment: no i didnt mean to initially. it sort of helped but now my goal is to just make the code work (while using majority of my code). so what should i add to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by `make it work`? Do you just want a `return`?

Comment: sorry im very new to coding. when i mean make it work i mean to run the whole code and have it do whatever the code was intended. i really apologize if my questions arnt awesomely worded

Comment: I can't tell what is intended. You haven't explained that yet.

Comment: `a=input("choose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower()`

Comment: ill reask the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments that **In  theWhere_do_u_want_to_fight()    function, if a does not match any of the choices, you're assigning the new user input to a variable named place. Which means a never changes, and the loop runs forever**

so just use return function in the else condition where you call the **where_do_you_want_to_fight()** again without assigning it to the new variable

```
    print("you will be "+x)
    print("Great choice!")

def who_do_you_want_to_face(a, x):
    print(a + " will face "+x + "\n" )

def Where_do_u_want_to_fight(a):

 while True:

    if a=="pokemon stadium":
        print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
        print("Well also give you pokemon stadium music too but im in a rush")
        break
        
    elif a=="planet namek":
        print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
        print("Well also give you planet namek music too but im in a rush")
        break
        
    elif a=="the leaf village":
        print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
        print("Well also give you the leaf village music too but im in a rush")
        break
        
    else:
        print("Spell it correctly!\n")
        return Where_do_u_want_to_fight(input("\nchoose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower())


        

        

character=input("write what pokemon you want to be (charzard, pikachu, or Gyarados) :").lower()
who_do_you_want_to_be(character)

choice=input("\nwrite what pokemon you want to face (charzard, pikachu, or Gyarados) :").lower()
who_do_you_want_to_face(character, choice)

place=input("\nchoose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower()
Where_do_u_want_to_fight(place)
```